# How do I add a PPA in a shell script without user input?

Tags: ppa, scripts

Basically, I want to run `add-apt-repository ppa:(whatever)` without the "press Enter to continue" prompt. How would I do this?

Essentially, I want to deploy adding a repository in a shell script without user input.

Comment: Just add `-y` at the end of the command `add-apt-repository -y ...`.

Comment: `man add-apt-repository` and you will see the `-y` switch that @UriHerrera said.

Answer (score 121, accepted):

The script goes like this

```
#! /bin/sh
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:(Your ppa here) -y
```

BTW you will still have to enter **password**.

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: aditya, you man Its Working :D , just now checked...

Comment: You should run the script as root, so you don't need `sudo` and thus no password